# How to run pmcmd commands in parallel and track their status

Tags: unix, parallel-processing

I have a set 6 workflows, which has dependency on each. Once the first workflow completes successfully, it need to trigger both second and third workflow in parallel. If both the second and third workflows are completed successfully, it must trigger fourth and fifth workflows in parallel. When the fourth and fifth workflows completes successfully, sixth workflow must be triggered. If any of the size workflows gets failed, the script must exit abruptly without proceeding further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite succinctly with **GNU Parallel**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Halt on error
set -e

################################################################################
# Run workflow 1
################################################################################
./workflow1

################################################################################
# Run workflows 2 and 3 in parallel, killing the other if either dies
################################################################################
parallel --halt now,fail=1 ::: ./workflow2 ./workflow3

################################################################################
# Run workflows 4 and 5 in parallel, killing the other if either dies
################################################################################
parallel --halt now,fail=1 ::: ./workflow4 ./workflow5

################################################################################
# Run workflow 6
################################################################################
./workflow6
```

Or, without **GNU Parallel**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Halt on error
set -e

################################################################################
# Run workflow 1
################################################################################
./workflow1

################################################################################
# Run workflows 2 and 3 in parallel
################################################################################
./workflow2 &
p2=$!
./workflow3 &
p3=$!
wait $p2 && wait $p3

################################################################################
# Run workflows 4 and 5 in parallel
################################################################################
./workflow4 &
p4=$!
./workflow5 &
p5=$!
wait $p4 && wait $p5

################################################################################
# Run workflow 6
################################################################################
./workflow6
```

Comment: I don't this will be capturing the workflow status if it is failed or aborted or succeeded. My code need to go ahead based on the return status of the workflows.

Comment: It stops if there is an error and it proceeds if the workflows are successful - as you asked. Please try it! Make 6 workflows, each one a separate little `bash` script that says `starting, sleeping 5 seconds, exit` and make one of them exit with status 1 and you will see that the above script stops when the failing script exits.

Comment: Can I use the same script in ksh? I'm trying this code to execute workflows in parallel. `(pmcmd startworkflow -sv infa951 -d INFA -u P2L_USR -pv P2L_PWD -f LDW -wait wf_DAILY_LOAD; echo $?) & (pmcmd startworkflow -sv infa951 -d INFA -u P2L_USR -pv P2L_PWD -f LDW -wait wf_DAILY_INCR_LOAD; echo $?)` Instead of echo. I'm unable to assign the status to a variable

Comment: It's in `bash`, because `bash` has the functionality you need. Just use `bash` for this one - it just means a different line at the start in the shebang line.